# python dynamically inherit class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to do dynamic inheritance in python?
I am trying to select one of the netmiko class in the `SuperSwitch` class during runtime and based on the argument `device_type` and `connection_type`

any help would be appreciated

For example:

```
mapper = {
    'juniper': {
        'telnet': JuniperTelnet,
        'ssh': JuniperSSH
    },
    'cisco': {
        'telnet': CiscoIosTelnet,
        'ssh': CiscoIosSSH
    }
}

class SuperSwitch:
    def __init__(self, device_type, connection_type, ip, port, user, pw):
        # how can I dynamically inherit the class based on the device_type and connection_type
        # for example mapper['juniper']['telnet']
        device_args = dict(
            device_type='{d}_{conn}'.format(p=device_type, conn=connection_type),
            ip=ip,
            port=port,
            username=user,
            password=pw,
        )
        super().__init__(**device_args)

    def my_send_command(self, cmd):
        print("running:", cmd)
        super().send_command(cmd)


class MyJuniper(SuperSwitch):
    def __init__(self, device_type, connection_type, ip, port, user, pw):
        super().__init__(device_type, connection_type, ip, port, user, pw)
    def my_send_command(self, cmd):
        super().my_send_command(cmd)
        # my other code


sw = MyJuniper('juniper', 'telnet', '10.0.0.2', 1234, 'user', 'pw')
sw.my_send_command('show ?')
```

Comment: under `SuperSwitch` class y are you calling `super().send_command(cmd)` ?

Comment: @also what is `JuniperTelnet` in mapper dict?

Comment: Don't. Just have both versions, and a function that returns either type depending on the arguments.

Comment: @JacksonPro, I am trying to inherit from one of the netmiko class. so if I am using JuniperTelnet, I am calling the JuniperTelnet.send_command

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, or at least i don't know how you can do that. But you can hide your implementation inside the superswitch, that's what classes as for.

```
mapper = {
    'juniper': {
        'telnet': JuniperTelnet,
        'ssh': JuniperSSH
    },
    'cisco': {
        'telnet': CiscoIosTelnet,
        'ssh': CiscoIosSSH
    }
}

class DummyImplementation():
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.args = kwargs
    
    def send(self, cmd):
        print(cmd)

def get_right_implementation(device_type, connection_type):
    # do you magic!
    return DummyImplementation

class SuperSwitch:
    def __init__(self, device_type, connection_type, ip, port, user, pw):
        # how can I dynamically inherit the class based on the device_type and connection_type
        # for example mapper['juniper']['telnet']
        implementation_class = get_right_implementation(device_type, connection_type)
        device_args = dict(
            device_type='{d}_{conn}'.format(p=device_type, conn=connection_type),
            ip=ip,
            port=port,
            username=user,
            password=pw,
        )
        self.implementation = implementation_class(**device_args)


    def my_send_command(self, cmd):
        self.implementation.send(cmd)
```